# What it means for an object $x$ to be an element in the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

does this solution is correct for :
$A \setminus (B\ \cup\ C)?$. First, I transformed it to:
$x \in A\ \land\ \lnot(x\ \in\ (B\ \cup\ C)) - \text{Definition of } \setminus\\
x \in A\ \land\ (\lnot(x\ \in B\ \lor\ x \in C)) - \text{Definition of}\ \cup\\
x \in A\ \land(\lnot(x\ \in B)\ \land\ \lnot(x\ \in C)) - \text{De Morgan}\\
x \in A\ \land (x \notin B\ \land\ x \notin C) - \text{Definition of }\notin\\
x \in A\ \cap\ (x \notin B\ \land x \notin C) - \text{Definition of } \cap\\
\text{ and  ended up with}:\ x \in A\ \cap\ (B^c\ \cap\ C^c)$

Comment: Why would $A \cap (x \not\in B \land x\not\in C)$ imply $A \cap ( B \cap C)$ ?

Comment: "$(x \not \in B \land x \not \in C)$"  is not a set.  It is a statement of fact.  "$x \in A \cap (x\not \in B \land x \not \in C)$" is a meaningless arrangement of symbols.  It's like saying "Harry Potter is a wizard intersected with Harry Potter is not a rabbit and Harry Potter doesn't eat ice cream"

Comment: I am pretty new to this, so any point of view is welcomed. However, a bit more clarity of how to solve this from your point of view will be really helpful for me to understand it better. Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mistake in the first line$$x \in A\ \land\ \lnot(x\ \in\ (B\ \color{red}\cap\ C)) $$

Notice that we have

$$A \setminus D = A \cap D^c$$

Let $D = B \cap C$ and apply De Morgan's Law.

- Edit after the question is edited:

Now mistake at last line, note that $x \notin B$ means $x \in B^\color{red}c$.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo on the condition line (it's too early here).

Comment: answer edited for mistake at last line.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So in this case if I understand correctly: x belongs of the intersection of A and the intersection of the complements of B and C?

Comment: $x$ belongs to the intersection of $A$ and the intersection of the (complements of $B$)  and the (complements of $C$).

Comment: Many thanks for the help.